# Show popup after validator in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html

I want to show popup while user registering.

The code I use works well:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>PROCESSING</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("btnLogin");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbMail" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="60px" Width="300px" placeholder="Mail Address" Font-Names="SF Pro Text" Font-Size="14pt" TextMode="Email" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="2px"></asp:TextBox>
```

However, I use `TextMode="Email"` and `ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"`, so it's kind of a validator that checks for syntax.

When I use this, both popup and error message are displayed at the same time like below:

[image]

I only want to show the popup when the validator is OK (syntax etc..)

Comment: Why are you lettings them get to the point where the processing box shows up when the form is invalid already?  Make sure the form is valid before showing the processing box on the client side.

Comment: @Dylan Hello, are you here ? My question is that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the code to show your popup inside the form's `onsubmit` instead of the button's `onclick`. This way, your popup will only be displayed when you pass all the validations and the form is ready to submit:

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
  return false; //This line is for demo. Remove it once you're done testing.
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="tbMail" type="email" placeholder="Mail Address" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" />
  <input id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>PROCESSING</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I added the `return false;` to prevent the form submission so you can see the popup, otherwise it will be too fast. Remove that line to let the form continue with the submission.